# TypeScript/JavaScript Private Members

Tags: javascript, typescript

The current ESNext contains a proposal for private members; for example:

```
class Person {

    #firstName;
    #lastName;

    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.#firstName = firstName;
        this.#lastName = lastName;
    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.#firstName} ${this.#lastName}`;
    }
}

const person = new Person("John", "Smith");
const firstName = person.firstName; // ERROR: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Person'.
const fullName = person.toString(); // John Smith
```

TypeScript has supported public, protected and private members *(IIRC)* since the very beginning, although they are erased since there is no JavaScript equivalent.

What I want to know is, whether TypeScript can be configured (current, on roadmap, or being discussed) to support mapping `private` to ESNext private members; for example:

```
class Person {

    constructor(private firstName: string = "", private lastName: string = "") {

    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
```

**Compiled (Target = ESNext)**

```
class Person {

    #firstName;
    #lastName;

    constructor(firstName = "", lastName = "") {
        this.#firstName = firstName;
        this.#lastName = lastName;
    }

    toString() {
        return `${this.#firstName} ${this.#lastName}`;
    }
}
```

**Compiled (Target <= ES2021)**

```
"use strict";
class Person {
    constructor(firstName = "", lastName = "") {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    toString() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, these are a bit different features. `private` keyword is a weak privacy whereas `#` syntax is much stronger privacy which is also a runtime privacy. Please see [release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#ecmascript-private-fields) and [which should I use](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#which-should-i-use)

Comment: Please keep in mind that `<=ES2021` compiles `#foo='value'` to a `WeakMap`. `private` keyword always just erased during the compilation

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks. Yes I did notice that when playing with the config in the playground, but I didn't want to make the SO question too verbose.